# How to create date count in which no transaction but it will show with previous count

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

My current output :

[image: Current output]

But I want putput like:

[image: want output like]

Note : I want -> if no transaction exists in some date, still that date will shown with previous date count.(from procedure in oracle)

Comment: It would help if you would show the query that produces the "Current output", since the "putput" you want is probably easiest to get at the same time.

Comment: select * from table - only get that table data @mathguy

Comment: I don't understand. You have the counts saved in a table? Do you want to fill the dates between the earliest and the latest dates that exist in the table?

Comment: in current output, that data are in table..but i want that whicha date are missing till today will also fill n it takes previous dates count

Comment: could you please add your backend code for that you did so far to get yuor desired output, so we check and modify if needed

Comment: you want a select statement to do that or c# code?

Comment: procedure for get that output

Comment: Very likely a **procedure may not** be needed and the requirement may be met with by a query as suggested in one answer.

Answer (score 1):

here is a simple solution that might do the trick for you:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ed98d/1/0

```
with 
full_august as (
    select TO_DATE ('01.AUG.2018 00:00:00', 'DD.MON.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')+level-1 date_ 
    from dual connect by level <= 31),
possible_combinations as (
    select f.date_,t.count_,f.date_-t.date_ currentness 
    from full_august f left outer join t_ t on f.date_ >= t.date_)
select pc.date_,pc.count_ 
from possible_combinations pc
where pc.currentness  = (select min(currentness) from possible_combinations where date_ = pc.date_)
and   pc.date_       <= (select max(date_) from t_);

|      DATE_ | COUNT_ |
|------------|--------|
| 2018-08-18 |    200 |
| 2018-08-19 |    200 |
| 2018-08-20 |    400 |
| 2018-08-21 |    200 |
| 2018-08-22 |    200 |
| 2018-08-23 |    200 |
| 2018-08-24 |    200 |
| 2018-08-25 |    600 |
| 2018-08-26 |    800 |
```

Some additional info as requested by @dbusern:

- You can find the table structures behind the sqlfiddle link above
- The `connect by` construct is a 'Hierarchical Query', a very powerful construct. But it can also be (ab)used for simple things such as `select level from dual connect by level <= 10` to just get the numbers from 1 to 10.
- The `left join on f.date_ >= t.date_` makes that we can then compute via `f.date_-t.date_` which date from t is the least in the past compared to the date in f
- Then in the part `pc.currentness  = (select min(currentness)...` we discard all results that are not the most current past result
- The part `pc.date_       <= (select max(date_)` is just there to remove days that are past the max date in t, as this seemed to be a requirement
- You can try each part of the query by adding selects in between:

  ```
  with 
  full_august as (
      select TO_DATE ('01.AUG.2018 00:00:00', 'DD.MON.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')+level-1 date_ 
      from dual connect by level <= 31)
  select * from full_august;


  with 
  full_august as (
      select TO_DATE ('01.AUG.2018 00:00:00', 'DD.MON.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')+level-1 date_ 
      from dual connect by level <= 31),
  possible_combinations as (
      select f.date_,t.count_,f.date_-t.date_ currentness 
      from full_august f left outer join t_ t on f.date_ >= t.date_)
  select * from possible_combinations;
  ```

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the query , can you post the table structures and explain how the query works -the logic of it. I came across this post and trying to understand for my knowledge.

Comment: @dbusern added some more info for you